# How to add maximize and minimize button to jQuery Basic Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I need to add maximize and minimize button (should be functional) to a basic jQuery Dialog. Please find the below code for reference:

```js
$("#modalDiv").dialog({
  position: {
    my: "center center",
    at: "center center",
    of: window
  },
  width: 1100,
  height: 230,
  modal: true,
  showTitle: true,
  close: function() { }
});
```

Any help shall be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "*I don't want to use any plugin*" - uses jquery-ui - pick one.

Comment: TBH, it's a lot more than adding a couple of buttons.  Dialogs tend to be designed to be single-use (ie one at a time) and having a minimise button implies multiple can be open.  Then you need to position the closed dialog and handle it being re-opened / moved etc.  It's not a small task and if someone has already done it for you, then your best option is to use what they've done and move on to something more practical in your project.  If you're doing this to learn how, then you probably should start from scratch and not use jquery-ui.

Comment: Where do you want these buttons to appear? It might be helpful to include an image of what you're looking to see, what state they would be in. What function would you like them to perform? What does "minimize" look like versus "maximize"?

Comment: It should appear on the top title bar before close button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done within the `create` callback to add functional buttons. You're simply changing the `width` and `height` options of the `.dialog()` to specific values when each button is clicked.

The only thing to remember is that you want to call the `widget` when you want to add the buttons.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Delete all items": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    },
    create: function(e, ui) {
      var that = $(this);
      var dlg = $(this).dialog("widget");
      var min = $("<button>", {
          class: "ui-dialog-titlebar-min",
          type: "button",
          title: "Minimize"
        })
        .button({
          icon: "ui-icon-minusthick",
          showLabel: false
        });
      var max = $("<button>", {
          class: "ui-dialog-titlebar-max",
          type: "button",
          title: "Maximize"
        })
        .button({
          icon: "ui-icon-arrowthick-2-ne-sw",
          showLabel: false
        });
      var oSize = {
        width: that.dialog("option", "width"),
        height: that.dialog("option", "height"),
        position: {
          my: "center",
          at: "center",
          of: window
        }
      };
      var mSize = {
        width: $(window).width(),
        height: $(window).height(),
        position: {
          my: "left top",
          at: "left top",
          of: window
        }
      };
      min.click(function(e) {
        that.dialog("option", oSize);
      });
      max.click(function(e) {
        that.dialog("option", mSize);
      });
      $(".ui-dialog-titlebar .ui-dialog-title", dlg).after(min, max);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-dialog-titlebar span.ui-dialog-title {
  width: 83%;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar .ui-dialog-titlebar-min,
.ui-dialog-titlebar .ui-dialog-titlebar-max {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: -10px 0 0 0;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar .ui-dialog-titlebar-max {
  right: 1.75em;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar .ui-dialog-titlebar-min {
  right: 3.25em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Confirm">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>

<p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
```

This example is using all jQuery UI elements and widgets. As you can see, the two buttons change the size of the dialog. If you want them to do something else, you can easily update their click functions and you have access to all the elements.

You could also build this into it's own widget using the Widget Factory (See [Extending Widgets](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/)). This would be good if you want many dialog widgets to have these features.